# Low latency HLS stream and Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to live stream my PC screen to chromecast with low-latency (In my case it's not possible to use google chrome extension). I figured out that HLS would be the best options, but when mpegts segments (the ones from m3u8 playlist) are smaller than 25 frames chromecast simply doesn't play my stream, it just hangs up. Of course the bigger ts segments are, the less "live" my stream is, 25 frames minimal latency doesn't satisfy me. So I have three basic questions:

1. Is it possible with chromecast to play live HLS stream having ts segments as small as than 5-10 frames? How should I prepare them?
2. If not, is there any other way to achieve (ultra)low-latency live streaming with HLS and chromecast?
3. If not, is there any other way to achieve (ultra)low-latency live streaming for chromecast, preferably without using google chrome extension or android chromecast app?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your are trying to do is simply not possible with chromecast. The hardware can probably do it, but the media stack in the OS does not support any low latency protocols. I have achieved under 33ms on android TV and raspberry pi.

Comment: What do you mean that you've achieved under 33 ms on android TV and raspery PI - your overall latency was under 33 ms or mpeg ts segment's length? Have you used HLS or your custom protocol over TCP or UDP?

Comment: Overall latency.  Using custom protocol over TCP on LAN. For public internet, or long distance, I would use UDP with FEC. HLS, or any segmented/HTTP streaming will add a few seconds.